# How do I load a page in PHP without redirecting, based on session?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a index.php page that loads either the login page (login.php) or the actual page (main.php) based on the users session.
I know I could do it with redirecting, but I want to simply have everything on one "page".
What's the best way for doing this?

Comment: *"What's the best way for doing this?"* - There isn't a "best way", there's just "a" way. Plus, no code to boot, is all guesswork from hereon in. Tip: Conditional statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty of ways to achieve it. Check if the session is current and then display the `main.php` if so, otherwise display the login page.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    include('./main.php');
} else {
    include('./login.php');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    include('./main.php');
} else {
    include('./login.php');
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $userMSG = 'Welcome To My Website!';
    echo $userMSG;
} else {
    $userMSG = '<form id="login_Form">';
    $userMSG .= '<input id="log_u" name="log_u" type="text">';
    $userMSG .= '<input id="log_p" name="log_p" type="password">';
    $userMSG .= '</form>';
    echo $userMSG;
}
?>
```

The first way is what i think you want, but you can reduce pages the second way, by adding login into the homepage.